# how to run a python script after running a scala spark app

Tags: python-3.x, cron, scheduling

I want to run a python script just after the running a spark scala app.

I tried by

```
30 00 * * *  spark scala job command && python script2.py
```

but it doesn't run the python script

Comment: Do you use OS cron?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes ubuntu os

Answer (score 0):

First you have error in your line of cron. You need to have 3 `*`, not 4

```
30 0 * * * ...
```

next the good practice for `cron` is to create shell script which will run the commands. And in this script add sourcing of you `.bashrc` or/and `.bash_profile` to set your environment variables to be the same as when you login in to the OS.
One example script will looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/your/home/directory/.bashrc
# also you can try
# . /path/to/your/home/directory/.bash_profile
spark scala job command >/tmp/logfile 
retcode=$?
if [ "$errcode -eq 0 ]
then python script2.py
fi
```

About the last line it's wise to split it and make deep checks if the first command finish execution successfully.

Comment: 4 * is just a typing mistake in question, my scala script ran using the above mentioned command in the question but python script didn't run after scala`s completion

Comment: I have to mention the time in bashrc?

Comment: @experiment, what do you mean by "mention the time in bashrc"? the time is defined in cron record

Comment: You mention in few comments above. You should source this file to load your environment variables, PATH, etc

Comment: please give a detailed solution,I am new to this,not able pick through the above solution

Comment: and aren't they both similar,setting directly in crontab and setting it through bash file? why is only my scala script running and python script doesnt after scala script`s completion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186452/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-experiment).

Answer (score 0):

Whether your spark-submit ran successfully or not you will not get the answer using "$?" in shell as the status. To get the status of your spark job you need to run

```
yarn application -status <application id of the spark job>
```

Based on the result you run your if [ $condition ]
Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your feedback,but why does my python script not work after scala script completes?

Comment: As the shell command expects 0 or 1 value in the if condition its failing because of the variable value .spark submit i runs on cluster and the output you get after the spark-submit is typically 1 for various reasons. that is why even if your spark-submit is successful your python script is not running. the best way to check the status was the yarn command I have shared and then run the Python Script